# Pandas error - invalid value encountered

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, python-3.4, kaggle

I'm new to Pandas. I downloaded and installed [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).  Then I tried running the following code via the Spyder app:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv('/Users/Ben/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic/train.csv')
train
```

Although this prints the dataframe as I expected, it also shows these errors

```
//anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py:1969: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e8).any()
//anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py:1970: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) &
//anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py:1971: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  (abs_vals > 0)).any()
```

Why am I getting these errors?

EDIT: I just tested the above code in an `IPython` notebook and it works without errors.  So, is there something wrong with my `Spyder` installation?  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT2: After some testing, I can read the first 5 rows of the CSV without getting the warning.  So, I suspect a `NaN` in the 6th row for a `float64` type column is triggering the warning.

Comment: never seen this before but I use WinPython, could you try reinstalling anaconda

Comment: @EdChum Reinstalled Anaconda and I'm still getting this error

Comment: For anyone interested, you can download the train.csv dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)

Comment: There's a discussion about this on github [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9950).  You can work around this issue by doing `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x:'%f'%x)`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the original dataset? Or link to it?

Comment: It is indeed the NaN values causing the error - see answer to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955158/what-might-be-the-cause-of-invalid-value-encountered-in-less-equal-in-numpy

Comment: I had similar problem for percentile with NaN values.. by changing it to `nanpercentile` it worked perfectly without error. `nanpercentile` ignore nans.

Answer (score 33):

I have the same error and have decided that it is a bug. It seems to be caused by the presence of NaN values in a DataFrame in Spyder. I have uninstalled and reinstalled all packages and nothing has effected it. NaN  values are supported and are completely valid in DataFrames especially if they have a DateTime index.

In the end I have settled for suppressing this warnings as follows.

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action = "ignore", category = RuntimeWarning)
```