# RunTimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in greater

Tags: python, pandas

I am running the Ananconda 2.3 distribution of Python 3.4.3 in Spyder 2 and everyonce in a while when I am writing a line of code in the console, usually after I press the "(" key I get a RunTimeWarning, an example of a recent example can be found below:

```
foo = test_mod.isupply_df.copy(C:\Users\BLANK\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py:2037: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e8).any()
```

has anyone else experienced this type of problem, it doesn't seem to be causing any problems that I can notice and has mainly been an annoyance but I am sure it is messing something up on a deeper level and I would like to fix it.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: I have seen this issue as well, also in Python 3.5.  Seems to happen all of a sudden and only when you open perenetheses, suggesting it's an autocomplete issue.  You can disable warnings before opening iPython consoles in the Preferences, but obviously that's not a great solution.

Comment: May be related to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519487/pandas-error-invalid-value-encountered

Comment: This looks to be a bug in Spyder.  I can't consistently reproduce the error, but I don't get it when using iPython in the terminal, consistent with the other SO question linked above.  It seems something about how Pandas formats its float output conflicts with Spyder.  I would submit an issue here:  https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues