# What might be the cause of 'invalid value encountered in less_equal' in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, runtime

I experienced a RuntimeWarning

```
 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
```

Generated by this line of code of mine:

```
center_dists[j] <= center_dists[i]
```

Both `center_dists[j]` and `center_dists[i]` are numpy arrays

What might be the cause of this warning ?

Comment: Are the numpy arrays of equal length?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inequality comparison of numpy array with nan to a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345843/inequality-comparison-of-numpy-array-with-nan-to-a-scalar)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That's most likely happening because of a `np.nan` somewhere in the inputs involved. An example of it is shown below -

```
In [1]: A = np.array([4, 2, 1])

In [2]: B = np.array([2, 2, np.nan])

In [3]: A<=B
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
Out[3]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

For all those comparisons involving `np.nan`, it would output `False`. Let's confirm it for a [`broadcasted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) comparison. Here's a sample -

```
In [1]: A = np.array([4, 2, 1])

In [2]: B = np.array([2, 2, np.nan])

In [3]: A[:,None] <= B
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
Out[3]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Please notice the third column in the output which corresponds to the comparison involving third element `np.nan` in `B` and that results in all `False` values.

Comment: How can I avoid printing the RuntimeWarning? I'm doing a lot comparison that has nan, so I don't want to print them all....

Comment: @LWZ You don't want to print the RuntimeWarning or you want to tell which comparisons were because of comparing with NaNs?

Comment: I don't want to print the RuntimeWarning.

Comment: @LWZ Use this : `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category =RuntimeWarning)` at the top of the script?

Comment: Interestingly, if the arrays contain a single element (one of which is NaN), no warning is issued (which could make one think that NaN comparison is not the real issue with the warning).

Comment: Re: `warnings.filterwarnings()`, using `with np.errstate()` is usually better.  For details, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537961/1628638).

Answer (score 23):

As a follow-up to Divakar's answer and his comment on how to suppress the `RuntimeWarning`, a safer way is suppressing them only **locally** using `with np.errstate()` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html)): it is good to generally be alerted when comparisons to `np.nan` yield `False`, and ignore the warning only when this is really what is intended.  Here for the OP's example:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
  center_dists[j] <= center_dists[i]
```

Upon exiting the `with` block, error handling is reset to what it was before.

Instead of `invalid value encountered`, one can also ignore all errors by passing `all='ignore'`.  Interestingly, this is missing from the `kwargs` in the docs for `np.errstate()`, but not in the ones for [`np.seterr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).  (Seems like a small bug in the `np.errstate()` docs.)

Comment: A perfect solution, thank you. I usually keep `nan`s on purpose because I know they will eventually fail all comparisons and get masked.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above answers another way to suppress this warning is [to use `numpy.less` explicitly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less.html), supplying the `where` and `out` parameters:

```py
np.less([1, 2], [2, np.nan])
```

outputs: `array([ True, False])` causing the runtime warning,

```py
np.less([1, 2], [2, np.nan], where=np.isnan([2, np.nan])==False)
```

does not calculate result for the 2nd array element [according to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less.html) leaving the value undefined (I got True output for both elements), while

```py
np.less([1, 2], [2, np.nan], where=np.isnan([2, np.nan])==False, out=np.full((1, 2), False)
```

writes the result into an array pre-initilized to False (and so always gives False in the 2nd element).

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to `Nan` values in dataframe, which is completely fine with DF.

In Pycharm, This worked like a charm for me:

```
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action = "ignore", category = RuntimeWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy dtypes are so strict. So it doesnt produce an array like `np.array([False, True, np.nan])`, it returns  `array([ 0.,  1., nan])` which a `float` array.

If you try to change a bool array like:

```
x= np.array([False, False, False])
x[0] = 5
```

will retrun `array([ True, False, False])`  ... wow

But I think  `5>np.nan` cannot be `False`, it should be `nan`, `False` would mean that a data comparison has been made and it returned the result like `3>5`, which I think it's a disaster. Numpy produces data that we actually don't have. If it could have returned `nan` then we could handle it with ease.

So I tried to modify the behavior with a function.

```py
def ngrater(x, y):
    with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
        c=x>y
        c=c.astype(np.object)
        c[np.isnan(x)] = np.nan
        c[np.isnan(y)] = np.nan
        return c
a = np.array([np.nan,1,2,3,4,5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]) #9 elements
b = np.array([0,1,-2,-3,-4,-5, -5, -5, -5]) #9 elements

ngrater(a,b)
```

returns:
`array([nan, False, True, True, True, True, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)`

But I think whole memory structure is changed in that way. Instead of getting a memory-block with uniform unites, it will produce a block of pointers, where the real data is somewhere else. So function may perform slower and probably that's why Numpy doesn't do that. We need a `superBool` dtype which will contain also `np.nan`, or we just have to use float arrays `+1:True, -1:False,  nan:nan`